# Make UIImageView fit width of screen but keep aspect ratio [swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface, interface-builder

I'm trying to build a simple tableview with a tableView showing a list of images people posted and comments their friends added.

[image]

This is a subclass of TableViewCell, and I used stack views to lay it out. The problem is that I want to show the photos without stretching them - I want them to keep their original aspect ratio, but people can upload images of any dimensions. You see in the screenshot that the image is squished.

What I noticed is that the larger the uploaded .jpeg file, the taller the cells grew (I'm guessing the image size is dictating the intrinsic height?), but since the width can't change, each image is squished differently. A huge picture will show up super tall but with the same width.

I tried setting the image to Aspect Fit, but only the visible image itself does what I want: fit to width and not warp the aspect ratio. However, the UIImageView itself is still super tall and pushing all other UI elements out of the way.

I must be missing something here... It shouldn't be so hard, should it?

Comment: show the code you use to layout the cell, and code of the `cellForRowAt`

Comment: I agree with Milan `cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I made the interface in the storyboard, and just used this in my cellForRowAt:

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:       "PostContentCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    cell.initializeData(thisPost: post)
    return cell

Comment: then `initializeData` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To constraint the image as aspect ratio , first give it width of screen , then give it a static height in IB and hook that constraint as IBOutlet

and set it inside cellForRow

```
   cell.imageHeightcon.constant = imageRealHeight*imageWidthInIB/imageRealWidth
```

Comment: This fixed my issue... mostly. The only problem is the IB preview is broken depending on what I put in as the build time constraint. At run time it's fine.

Comment: it may be broken , because the cell always need content constraints to fit with it's current height in IB

Answer (score -1):

You should fix the size of the image view for whatever you want. Then you should use aspect to fill instead of aspect to fit and select the option `clip to bounds` in the attribute inspection

Comment: Hi Tiago, could you please elaborate? What do you mean by "fix the size of the image view for whatever you want"? I tried just using aspect fit and using clip to bounds, which ended up cropping the image. It's good that it's no longer distorting it but I can't see the whole picture.